# What is the drawing on Tomoko's shirt?

Tags: watamote

In episode 4, Tomoko is using a shirt with a drawing.

[image: Mokocchi and her shirt]

The shirt has a drawing of a face, and すぐる (suguru) written on it.

Since this series makes references to others quite often, I wondered if the shirt is a reference to something.
If not, does the shirt have any significance at all?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.wordsense.eu/Suguru/ seems to define *suguru* as "male given name".
As far as referencing goes, I think it'd be reasonable to say it's just a picture of a guy's face where an equivalent to "guy" is written underneath.

Comment: I don't really buy this explanation. It seems too arbitrary. As noted [here](http://netyougo.com/2ch/6572.html), _suguru_ is internet slang derived from すぎる _sugiru_ that roughly means something like "too much" or "excessively". I have a strong sense that Tomoko's shirt is related to this usage of _suguru_, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what the relationship is.

Comment: Perhaps it's a double entendre. I could buy that she'd wear shirt that promoted "excessively" into "guys", "into" being that she's wearing a shirt of a guy. But I might be a little too imaginative. Or maybe the right amount. Hope you have better luck finding a better relationship of the two. I'd like to be sure in the end.

Comment: Suguru is also a common forename in Japanese.